# Insert a line break into Assembly code Easy 68k (68000)

Tags: assembly, 68000

I am very new to assembly, and I'm trying to build a small program. I can't figure out how to insert a line break in assembly using the Easy68k. For example, I am starting to write  basic black jack simulator, and I need to do a line break after greeting the first player. I tried incorporating "\n" into the variable declaration, but it just prints out as if it were part of the text.

According to the Easy 68K Help I/O section, I can use
"LF  EQU  $0A   New line (line feed)" but I have no idea how to implement this.

```
START   ORG        $400             ; Start of program area
    CLR.L      D0               ; Clear D0
    CLR.L      D1               ; Clear D1
    CLR.L      D2               ; Clear D2
    CLR.L      D3               ; Clear D3
    CLR.L      D4               ; Clear D4
    CLR.L      D5               ; Clear D5
    CLR.L      D6               ; Clear D6
    MOVE.L     playerTotal, D2  ; Store Player total in D1
    MOVE.L     card, D3         ; Store current card in D2
    MOVE.B     playerAce, D4    ; Store number of aces player has in D3
    MOVE       #14, D0      
    LEA        playerGreeting, A1   ; Load Player Greeting in A1
    TRAP       #15              ; Display Player Greeting
* insert line break     
    STOP       #$2700  ; Stop execution

        ORG         $1000   ;Start of data area
playerTotal DS.L        1       ; Save 1 byte of memory for playerTotal
dealerTotal DS.L        1       ; Save 1 byte of memory for dealerTotal
card        DC.L        5       ; Save 1 byte of memory for card dealt
keepPlaying DS.B        1       ; Save 1 byte of memory for Play again value
playerAce   DS.B        1       ; Save 1 byte of memory to track player Aces
playerGreeting  DC.B        'Hello Player 1!', 0    ; Message 

                LF        EQU       $0A
                END     START                  ; End of program and entry point
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
CR EQU $0D
LF EQU $0A
playerGreeting  DC.B        'Hello Player 1!',CR,LF,0    ; Message
```

This will insert a carriage return (CR) and line feed (LF) after your message. Basically it tacks on two additional characters to your output string before the null terminator (0).

Comment: Omg, amazing. Thanks!!! For any future reader, make sure you define CR in the info section as "CR  EQU  $0D   ;Carriage Return"  (in addition to LF).

Comment: @kelly, good point. I updated the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you would need carriage return? I'm confused as to what a carriage actually is. Wouldn't new line be sufficient to stop the string and move down?

Comment: @kaz It depends on what you are looking to do. A new line simply moves the cursor down one line but it stays in the same column. The carriage return moves the cursor to the beginning of the line. The two together operate like a "typewriter".